# Multiple A record and session/cookie

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record, session, cookie

For example I setup multiple a record for a domain

> abc.com
>   115.11.22.33
>   115.11.22.34
>   115.11.22.35

Is it true that if one browser successfully establishes a connection to one of the ip's, it will stick with this ip until it no longer works?

And is the cookie and session setup still valid in case the user connects through another ip?

Comment: I think it will stick with one IP until the DNS TTL expires..

Answer (score 2):

[David Houde’s answer](https://serverfault.com/a/504412) is correct. But I think there’s some confusion over how you have to manage cookies and sessions.

As long as the user keeps hitting 115.11.22.33, then the session data does not have to be available on 115.11.22.34 or 115.11.22.35. The browser will usually keep using the same IP. But there are a few instances where that will not be the case. For both load balancing and high availability, you need to ensure that the current session data is available on all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of users will experience the same DNS resolution when interacting in a short period of time. The IP may change when the DNS Time To Live (TTL) expires.

Sessions are based off the domain, and not IP address. They will work regardless of the IP.